# Cumulative constraint expression over indexed set in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

Using the following simplified model:

```
model = ConcreteModel()

model.WEEKS = Set(initialize = [1,2,3])
model.PRODS = Set(initialize = ['Q24','J24','F24'])
model.MONTHS = Set(initialize = ['J24','F24'])

model.volume = Var(model.WEEKS,model.PRODS, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
model.auction = Var(model.WEEKS,model.PRODS, within = Binary)

model.HedgeMin = Param(model.WEEKS,model.MONTHS, within = NonNegativeIntegers, initialize = {(1,'J24'):45,(1,'F24'):45,
                                                                                (2,'J24'):90,(2,'F24'):90,
                                                                                (3,'J24'):135,(3,'F24'):135})

model.HedgeMax = Param(model.WEEKS,model.MONTHS, within = NonNegativeIntegers, initialize = {(1,'J24'):60,(1,'F24'):60,
                                                                                (2,'J24'):120,(2,'F24'):120,
                                                                                (3,'J24'):180,(3,'F24'):180})
```

I am attempting to construct a constraint that applies cumulative bounds to the product of `auction` * `volume` for each week in `model.WEEKS` and each month in `model.MONTHS`. using helpful guidance from @AirSquid's response to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025003/expression-with-cumulative-sum-in-pyomo), I have constructed the following:

```
def hedge_rule(model, i,j):
        subset = {x for x in model.WEEKS if x <= i}
        return (model.HedgeMin[i,j],
               sum(model.auction[i,j] * model.volume[i,j] for i in subset for j in model.MONTHS)
                model.HedgeMax[i,j])
model.hedge_const = Constraint(model.WEEKS,model.MONTHS, rule = hedge_rule)
```

Which produces the following constraint:

```
hedge_const : Size=6, Index=hedge_const_index, Active=True
    Key        : Lower : Body                                                                                                                                                                                    : Upper : Active
    (1, 'F24') :  45.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] :  60.0 :True
    (1, 'J24') :  45.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] :  60.0 :True
    (2, 'F24') :  90.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] : 120.0 :   True
    (2, 'J24') :  90.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] : 120.0 :   True
    (3, 'F24') : 135.0 : auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] + auction[3,J24]*volume[3,J24] + auction[3,F24]*volume[3,F24] : 180.0 :   True
    (3, 'J24') : 135.0 : auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] + auction[3,J24]*volume[3,J24] + auction[3,F24]*volume[3,F24] : 180.0 :   True
```

I believe that, because I am summing `auction[i,j]*volume[i,j]` over the set `model.MONTHS`, both `J24` and `F24` are included in each set declaration. So, for example:
`(1, 'F24')` =  `45.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] :  60.0`.

However, I would like to make it so that only the relevant months are included with each key. i.e.
`(1, 'F24')` = `45.0 :auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] :  60.0`
`(1, 'J24')` = `45.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] :  60.0`
`(2, 'F24')` = `90.0 :auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] : 120.0`
`(2, 'J24')` = `90.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] +   auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] : 120.0`
etc.

My question is, is this possible with a single definition of `model.hedge_rule`? I imagine the solution will require the creation of separate sets for each element in `MONTHS` but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

As always, help and guidance much appreciated!

---

**Additional Details**
In response to @AirSquid's reply below:

In my simple formulation above, all elements of `PRODS` are currently associated with all elements of `WEEKS`. In this way @AirSquid's formulation of `WEEK_PROD` would actually output:

```
WEEK_PROD : Size=3, Index=WEEKS, Ordered=Insertion
    Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
      1 :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'Q24', 'J24', 'F24'}
      2 :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'Q24', 'J24', 'F24'}
      3 :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'Q24', 'J24', 'F24'}
```

For this reason, the formulation of `C1` wont quite produce the desired results as all products are summed across each week:

```
C1 : Size=3, Index=WEEKS, Active=True
    Key : Lower : Body                                                                                       : Upper : Active
      1 :   5.0 : auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24] + auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] :  10.0 :   True
      2 :   5.0 : auction[2,Q24]*volume[2,Q24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] :  10.0 :   True
      3 :   5.0 : auction[3,Q24]*volume[3,Q24] + auction[3,J24]*volume[3,J24] + auction[3,F24]*volume[3,F24] :  10.0 :   True
```

I am trying to end up with output indexed using keys `(week, product)` in which the `Q24` (or any product beginning 'Q') is excluded to produce the output examples in my original post.

Ultimately though, I'd like the relevant `(week,'Q24')` entries to be summed along with each entry for i.e. `J24` and`F24`. Note that this aspect of the problem was originally excluded in an attempt to keep things simpler in my post.

For clarity sake, this is the exact output I attempting to achieve:
**Output**

```
Key        : Lower : Body                                                                                                                                                     : Upper : Active
(1, 'F24') :  45.0 :auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24] :  60.0 :   True
(1, 'J24') :  45.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24]:  60.0 :   True
(2, 'F24') :  90.0 :auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] + auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24] + auction[2,Q24]*volume[2,Q24] : 120.0 :   True
(2, 'J24') :  90.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24] + auction[2,Q24]*volume[2,Q24]: 120.0 :   True
(3, 'F24') : 135.0 :auction[1,F24]*volume[1,F24] + auction[2,F24]*volume[2,F24] + auction[3,F24]*volume[3,F24] + auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24] + auction[2,Q24]*volume[2,Q24] + auction[3,Q24]*volume[3,Q24]: 180.0 :   True
(3, 'J24') : 135.0 :auction[1,J24]*volume[1,J24] + auction[2,J24]*volume[2,J24] + auction[3,J24]*volume[3,J24] + auction[1,Q24]*volume[1,Q24] + auction[2,Q24]*volume[2,Q24] + auction[3,Q24]*volume[3,Q24]: 180.0 :   True
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't totally clear what `MONTHS` is here, but you should definitely avoid repeating values from another set there, unless it is a subset of some kind.

I think you have some association of specific products with certain weeks, so the below is the approach that I would take.  You are effectively making a sparse set of `WEEKS * PRODS` and using that, which is good.

You can search my other answers for "indexed set" and I have posted other similar suggestions.

OBTW:  You appear to be (inadvertently?) building a non-linear (because you are multiplying variables) integer program which will be quite difficult to solve.  You should consider re-formulating to a MILP if at all possible.  And possibly consider making `volume` a continuous variable instead of integer if that is an acceptable simplification.  Perhaps look into making a big-M constraint instead of multiplying variables.

##### Code:

```
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel, Set, Var, Constraint

weekly_products = {
    1: ['Q24', 'J24'],
    2: ['Q24', 'F24'],
    3: ['F24']
}

model = ConcreteModel()

model.WEEKS = Set(initialize = [1,2,3])
model.PRODS = Set(initialize = ['Q24','J24','F24'])
# model.MONTHS = Set(initialize = ['J24','F24'])  <-- don't do this.  :)

# this is an "indexed set" which is a set of sets, indexed in this case by WEEKS
model.WEEK_PROD = Set(model.WEEKS, initialize=weekly_products)
model.WEEK_PROD_flat = Set(initialize=[(w, p) for w in model.WEEKS for p in model.WEEK_PROD[w]])

# initializing X with this reduced flat set will reduce errors and build a more compact
# model instead of |weeks| * |products| if there are only sparse legal combinations to consider:
model.X = Var(model.WEEK_PROD_flat)

def limit_rule(m, week):
    return (5, sum(m.X[week, product] for product in m.WEEK_PROD[week]), 10)

model.C1 = Constraint(model.WEEKS, rule=limit_rule)

model.pprint()
```

##### Output:

```
 4 Set Declarations
    PRODS : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'Q24', 'J24', 'F24'}
    WEEKS : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
    WEEK_PROD : Size=3, Index=WEEKS, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
          1 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'Q24', 'J24'}
          2 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'Q24', 'F24'}
          3 :     1 :    Any :    1 : {'F24',}
    WEEK_PROD_flat : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    Any :    5 : {(1, 'Q24'), (1, 'J24'), (2, 'Q24'), (2, 'F24'), (3, 'F24')}

1 Var Declarations
    X : Size=5, Index=WEEK_PROD_flat
        Key        : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 'J24') :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
        (1, 'Q24') :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
        (2, 'F24') :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
        (2, 'Q24') :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
        (3, 'F24') :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals

1 Constraint Declarations
    C1 : Size=3, Index=WEEKS, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body                : Upper : Active
          1 :   5.0 : X[1,Q24] + X[1,J24] :  10.0 :   True
          2 :   5.0 : X[2,Q24] + X[2,F24] :  10.0 :   True
          3 :   5.0 :            X[3,F24] :  10.0 :   True

6 Declarations: WEEKS PRODS WEEK_PROD WEEK_PROD_flat X C1
```

Comment: I'm out of office today and so wont get a chance to work on this but I just wanted to ensure I jumped on to say (yet another) big thanks for you taking the time to answer my questions @AirSquid. Also, I'll briefly respond to some of your points below.

Comment: 1.) `model.MONTHS` is indeed a subset of `model.PRODS`. It perhaps isn't clear given the extremely simplified example in my post but my actual model requires a couple of such subsets from the broader `PRODS` set. In light of your comments, I'll see if I can reformulate things as perhaps I can do away with the broader `PRODS` set and stick with the component subsets. Something for me to consider.

Comment: 2.) In my example, all products should actually be associated with all weeks. Despite this, I believe the creation of an indexed set should still solve the issue described. In addition though, the next iteration of the model I am developing will require the association of specific products with specific weeks and I had begun considering how to achieve this... you have inadvertently answered some inevitable future questions that I hadn't yet got to!

Comment: 3.) My model requires `volume` to be an integer variable, so changing that wont be possible. The multiplication of `auction * volume` is me using `auction` as a binary on/off for the volume variable. I don't really have a maths background and so wasn't familiar with the big M method. However, some cursory reading seems to indicate that this is exactly the sort of formulation that Big M should be employed in. Looks like I have some more homework to do ;-)

Comment: Regarding the non linear nature of my problem in its current form, would employing a non-linear solver resolve the issue? (Currently I'm using a linear solver - SCIP)

Comment: Additional details added to original post @AirSquid